# How do I define a DataRelation between a DataSet's DataTables on multiple columns?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

In my project there are two datatables `dtNames` and `dtDetails`.

I dont know about SQL. Here I am connecting to XML and Textfiles.

**dtNames**

```
EmpName    EmpRole

   a         2
   b         3
   c         4
```

**dtDetails**

```
 Empid     EmpName   EmpCity   EmpRole

  101        a         abc       3  //EmpRole not equal to above table EmpRole
  102        b         abc       3
  103        c         xyz       4
  104        d         pqr       5
  105        e         rst       6
```

I want to relate these two datatables based on the `EmpName` and `EmpRole` (here comparing to `dtNames`) and store the result in a DataSet `dsMain`(table from `dtDetails`) and then divide the two datatables in according to comparison like `matchedDataTable` and `unmatchedDataTable`.

I know this can be done using [DataRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014906/1577396) or [RowFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6007872/1577396) but i cant get a thought how to do this because there are two columns to be compared with other datatable two columns which i dont know.(I am beginner in .net)

I tried the below code: (*not working*)

```
            DataSet dsMain = new DataSet();
            DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("processData"
                , dtNames.Columns["EmpName"], dtDetails.Columns["EmpName"]);
            dsMain.Relations.Add(newRelation);
```

As you can see In the above code I am just comparing one column with other column. How compare with two. I am very close

please assist.

Comment: Check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx

Comment: I think this is linq? if it is then i dont want it. I know how to do using linq but my project is strictly non-linq. cant it be done using dataset rowfilters or datarelations..

Comment: As a side note: you might want to re-evaluate your database design (or your retrieval queries), as the datatables at the moment are not normalized (i.e. you are repeating the EmpRole data in both tables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the constructor that accepts column arrays:

```
DataSet dsMain = new DataSet();
DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("processData",
    new DataColumn[] { dtNames.Columns["EmpName"], dtNames.Columns["EmpRole"] },
    new DataColumn[] {dtDetails.Columns["EmpName"], dtDetails.Columns["EmpRole"]}
);
dsMain.Relations.Add(newRelation);
```

Comment: thank you, how to divide it into two tables like `matchedtable` and `unmatchedtable` ?

Comment: The relation will actually prevent unmatched rows to be added. To separate "matched" from "unmatched" you'll have to use plain old foreach loop.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the possible constructors of `DataRelation` ?

Just pass an array of `DataColumn`, and you can combine multiple columns.
Like so:

```
DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("test", new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns[0], dt1.Columns[1] },
                                                    new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns[0], dt2.Columns[1] });
```

Comment: thank you, how to divide it into two tables like matchedtable and unmatchedtable ?

Comment: 'Matching' of data (if I understand you correctly) should happen at database level, so before the data reaches your application. Of course, this depends on your specific situation.