# divide dataset in to matched and unmatched datatables

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

In my project there are two datasets `dsNames` and `dsDetails`.

I dont know about SQL. Here I am connecting to XML and Textfiles.

**dtNames**

```
EmployeeName    EmployeeRole

   a                2
   b                3
   c                4
```

**dtDetails**

```
 Empid     EmployeeName   EmpCity   EmployeeRole

  101        a             abc          3  //EmpRole not equal to above table EmpRole
  102        b             abc          3
  103        c             xyz          4
  104        d             pqr          5
  105        e             rst          6
```

I want to relate these two datasets based on the `EmployeeName` and `EmployeeRole` (here comparing to `dsNames`) and store the result in another DataSet `dsMain`(table from `dsDetails`) and then divide the two dataSets in according to comparison like `matchedDataTable` and `unmatchedDataTable`.

I know this can be done using [DataRelation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014906/1577396) or [RowFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6007872/1577396) but i cant get a thought how to do this because there are two columns to be compared with other datatable two columns which i dont know.(I am beginner in .net)

I tried the below code: (*not working*)

```
            foreach (DataRow rwMain in dsNames.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow rwSub in dsDetails.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (rwMain["EmployeeName"].Equals(rwSub["EmployeeName"]))
                    {
                        if (rwMain["EmployeeRole"].Equals(rwSub["EmployeeRole"]))
                        {
                            // Matched DataTable
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Unmatched DataTable
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am doing something wrong in the above code and also it looks me i am not doing it in a right way.

Please no linq because i know it but i cant use it in my project.

please assist.

Comment: i know linq but my project is strict non-linq

Comment: there are some methods like rowfilter, select, datarelation in datasets. but i am new to them. so i cant catch an idea how to relate and show the two datatable relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `Select` Property

```
 DataRow[] matchedRows = dtNames.Select("EmployeeName = '" + dsDetails.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString() + "'"
                    + " AND " + " EmployeeRole ='" + dsDetails.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString() + "'");
                //
 DataRow[] mismatchedRows = dsDetails.Tables[0].Select("EmployeeName <> '" + dtNames.Columns[0].ToString() + "'"
                    + " OR" + " EmployeeRole <>'" + dtNames.Columns[1].ToString() + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ, you just have to join both tables. Once by `EmpName` only and once by both columns.

```
var sameRoleNames = from rn in dtNames.AsEnumerable()
                join rd in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
                on new
                {
                    Name = rn.Field<string>("EmpName"),
                    Role = rn.Field<string>("EmpRole"),
                } equals new
                {
                    Name = rd.Field<string>("EmpName"),
                    Role = rd.Field<string>("EmpRole"),
                }
                select rd;
var notSameRoleNames = from rn in dtNames.AsEnumerable()
                   join rd in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
                   on rn.Field<string>("EmpName") equals rd.Field<string>("EmpName")
                   where rn.Field<string>("EmpRole") != rd.Field<string>("EmpRole")
                   select rd;
var matchedDataTable = sameRoleNames.CopyToDataTable();
var unmatchedDataTable = notSameRoleNames.CopyToDataTable();
```

I have only just seen your answer on the "can you use Linq" question. I leave it at that anyway, maybe it's helpful for someone else.